# Android kotlin MVVM - can you call viewmodel inside recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-recyclerview, rx-java

I have a list of objects and each object has it's own list of objects (which sometimes have a list too).

So I have one recyclerview for the list of main objects. Inside the adapter for the main objects, I create another recyclerview adapter for the list of secondary objects. (And the nesting continues like that if I get an object that has 3 nested lists)

I use the MVVM architecture. I receive my data from an API so I define the RxJava call (Disposable) inside the ViewModel, then create an instance of that ViewModel inside an Activity and load the data.

Now my question is, how can I load the data for the nested recyclerview lists? A viewModel is unique to an activity, and I can't call the viewModel inside an adapter (since I use dagger and inject only works in an activity)

Examples of data: So with these examples I would be getting a Person object, inside that object there's a list with Car objects, and inside that list another list of Submodel objects.

Nested json object:

```
{
    "personId": 1,
    "personName": "Bert",
    "personAge": 19,
    "isFemale": "false",
    "cars": [
                 {
            "carId": 1,
            "personId": 1,
            "carMake": "BWM",
            "model": "E36",
            "submodels": [{
                "submodelId": 1,
                "carId": 1,
                "submodelName": "335i"
            }, {
                "submodelId": 2,
                "carId": 1,
                "submodelName": "330d"
            }]
        }, {
            "carId": 2,
            "personId": 1,
            "carMake": "Porsche",
            "model": "911",
            "submodels": [{
                    "submodelId": 3,
                    "carId": 2,
                    "submodelName": "Carrera 4S"
                },
                {
                    "submodelId": 4,
                    "carId": 2,
                    "submodelName": "GT3 RS"
                }]
        }],
        "birthDate": "2000-06-28T00:00:00"

}
```

ApiInterface:

```
@GET("persons/{id}")
fun getPerson(@Path("id) id: Int: Observable<Person>
```

PersonRepo:

```
  class PersonsRepository @Inject constructor(val apiInterface: ApiInterface) {
 fun getPersons(personId: Int): Observable<Person>{
   return apiInterface.getPerson(personId)
 }
}
```

PersonViewModel:

```
class PersonViewModel @Inject constructor(private val personRepositoy: PersonRepository) : ViewModel() {
  var personResult: MutableLiveData<Person> = MutableLiveData()
  var personError: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
  lateinit var personDisposable: Disposable

  fun personResult(): LiveData<Person> {
    return personResult
  }
  fun personError(): LiveData<String> {
    return personError
  }

  fun loadPerson(personId: Int) {
    personDisposable = personRepository
    .getPerson(personId)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({
      personResult.postValue(it)
  }, {
      personError.postValue(it.message)
  })

  fun disposeElements(){
      if(::personDisposable.isInitialized && !personDisposable.isDisposed) {
            personDisposable.dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

The models would look like this:
PersonModel:

```
data class Person (
  @Json(name = "personId")
  val personId: Int,

  @Json(name = "personName")
  val name: String,

  @Json(name = "personAge")
  val age: Int,

  @Json(name = "isFemale")
  val isFemale: Boolean,

  @Json(name = "cars")
  val cars: List<Car>

  @Json(name = "birthDate")
  val birthDate: GregorianCalendar

)
```

Car:

```
data class Car(
  @Json(name = "carId")
  val carId: Int,

  @Json(name = "carMake")
  val carMake: String,

  @Json(name = "model")
  val model: String,

  @Json(name = "submodels")
  val submodels: List<SubModel>
)
```

SubModel:

```
data class SubModel(
  @Json(name = "submodelId")
  val submodelId: Int,

  @Json(name = "carId")
  val carId: Int,

  @Json(name = "submodelName")
  val submodelName: String
)
```

Comment: You may consider shortening the question by removing unnecessary code from it...

Comment: How did you later solve this Walt, because i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about dagger, but it seems that pure compile-time declaration based injection is clearly a limitation that will lead to bad code in this case. DI is not an all-problem-solving tool, it sometimes even makes things worse, especially when targeting JVM-implementations.

Comment: Yes it could be, but it also has it's benefits and it's too late to undo everything with Dagger now. Also if I didn't use dagger, it's still not a good idea to make API calls inside an adapter I think, because I'm using MVVM

Comment: You don't have to undo everything. Just try to adapt to it. Is there any possibility to register and resolve dependencies during runtime (such as Container.register(foo))? That might help gaining flexibility.